# Why is my Pytorch code significantly slower than Tensorflow?

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, pytorch

I am trying to move my code from Tensorflow to Pytorch. Before doing this, I just simply test myself two frameworks. I expected two frameworks should show similar performance. However, in my simple benchmark code, Tensorflow is much faster than Pytorch. I could not find the reason why Pytorch is slow.

Below is my TF code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
import time

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
    try:
        # Currently, memory growth needs to be the same across GPUs
        for gpu in gpus:
            tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
        logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
        print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
    except RuntimeError as e:
        # Memory growth must be set before GPUs have been initialized
        print(e)

tf.get_logger().setLevel('WARNING')
my_dtype = 'float32'
tf.keras.backend.set_floatx(my_dtype)


#%% Generate data set
x = np.linspace(0, 10, int(3 * np.power(2, 12))).astype('float32')
y = np.sin(x).astype('float32')

training_data_sets_tuple = (x, y)
dataset_imported = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(training_data_sets_tuple)
batch_size = np.power(2, 12)
dataset_imported = dataset_imported.batch(batch_size)

#%% Create model
num_neuron = 120
num_hidden_layers = 5
act_hidden = 'tanh'

layer_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=my_dtype)
layer_dense = [0] * num_hidden_layers

for i in range(num_hidden_layers):
    if i == 0:
        layer_dense[i] = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_neuron,
                                               activation=act_hidden, dtype=my_dtype)(layer_input)
    else:
        layer_dense[i] = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_neuron, activation=act_hidden, dtype=my_dtype)(layer_dense[i - 1])
layer_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name='', dtype=my_dtype)(layer_dense[-1])
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=layer_input, outputs=layer_output, name='mainnetwork')

optimizer_main_net = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)
loss_fn_main_net = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
#%% tf.function
@tf.function
def my_training(model, mini_batch):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        pred_output = model(mini_batch[0], training=True)
        loss_val = loss_fn_main_net(pred_output, mini_batch[1])
    grads = tape.gradient(loss_val, model.trainable_weights)
    optimizer_main_net.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
    return loss_val

#%% training
epoch = 1

tic = time.perf_counter()
while epoch < 1e3 + 1:
    loss_epoch = 0
    for step, mini_batch in enumerate(dataset_imported):
        loss_val = my_training(model, mini_batch)
        loss_epoch += float(loss_val)
    loss_epoch = loss_epoch / len(dataset_imported)
    if epoch % 200 == 0:
        toc = time.perf_counter()
        print(f'Epoch: {epoch}, Elapsed: {(toc-tic):.2f} sec')
        tic = time.perf_counter()
        print("Loss for Training on Epoch " +str(epoch) + " is "+ str(loss_epoch))

    epoch += 1
```

Below is my PT code

```
import numpy as np
import time
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import os
from torchsummary import summary

os.environ['CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING'] = "1"
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
torch.set_default_dtype(torch.float32)

# %% Dataset
x = np.linspace(0, 10, int(3 * np.power(2, 12))).astype('float32')
y = np.sin(x).astype('float32')


class MyDataset_simple(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, x, y, device):
        self.x = torch.tensor(x.reshape(-1, 1)).to(device)
        self.y = torch.tensor(y.reshape(-1, 1)).to(device)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.y)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.x[i], self.y[i]


dataset_simple = MyDataset_simple(x, y, device)
my_batch_size = int(np.power(2, 12))
train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset_simple, batch_size=my_batch_size)


# %% Model
class MyBenchModelSimple(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyBenchModelSimple, self).__init__()
        self.my_layer = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(1, 120),
                                      nn.Tanh(),
                                      nn.Linear(120, 120),
                                      nn.Tanh(),
                                      nn.Linear(120, 120),
                                      nn.Tanh(),
                                      nn.Linear(120, 120),
                                      nn.Tanh(),
                                      nn.Linear(120, 120),
                                      nn.Tanh(),
                                      nn.Linear(120, 1))

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.my_layer(x)
        return x


model = MyBenchModelSimple().to(device)
summary(model, input_size=(1,))
# %% Training
epoch = 1
my_loss_func = nn.MSELoss()
my_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params=model.parameters(), lr=1e-4)

tic = time.perf_counter()
model.train()
while epoch < 1e3 + 1:
    loss_individual_epoch = 0
    for i, (train_input_x, train_input_y) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        my_optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(train_input_x)

        loss = my_loss_func(outputs, train_input_y)
        loss.backward()
        my_optimizer.step()
        loss_individual_epoch += loss.item()
    loss_individual_epoch = loss_individual_epoch / len(train_dataloader)

    if epoch % 200 == 0:
        toc = time.perf_counter()
        print(f'Epoch: {epoch}, Elapsed: {(toc - tic):.0f} sec')
        tic = time.perf_counter()
        print("Loss for Training on Epoch " + str(epoch) + " is " + str(loss_individual_epoch))

    epoch += 1
```

For two frames, the model parameters are the same as 58,441.
Here is my result for TF code.

```
Epoch: 200, Elapsed: 5.58 sec
Loss for Training on Epoch 200 is 0.2962424506743749
Epoch: 400, Elapsed: 5.22 sec
Loss for Training on Epoch 400 is 0.2422607938448588
Epoch: 600, Elapsed: 5.24 sec
Loss for Training on Epoch 600 is 0.20201120525598526
Epoch: 800, Elapsed: 5.24 sec
Loss for Training on Epoch 800 is 0.14385090892513594
Epoch: 1000, Elapsed: 4.57 sec
Loss for Training on Epoch 1000 is 0.022997068629289668
```

Below is my result for PY code

```
Epoch: 200, Elapsed: 14 sec
Loss for Training on Epoch 200 is 0.2270326167345047
Epoch: 400, Elapsed: 13 sec
Loss for Training on Epoch 400 is 0.18032070621848106
Epoch: 600, Elapsed: 13 sec
Loss for Training on Epoch 600 is 0.14652210349837938
Epoch: 800, Elapsed: 14 sec
Loss for Training on Epoch 800 is 0.07957464456558228
Epoch: 1000, Elapsed: 13 sec
Loss for Training on Epoch 1000 is 0.06703292826811473
```

Where might I have made a mistake in the PT code?

Comment: You can use `pin_memory` and `num_workers` to push speed a bit. Not sure why the time difference is so significant. My guess is probably `optimizer.zero_grad` is taking time. Try to benchmark after commenting out that line.

Comment: @harshraj22: Thanks for the comment. I couldn't increase num_worker since I am working on Windows and there seem to have some limitations in multithreading.
Also, I removeed 'optimizer.zero_grad' and ran the code. Unfortunately, the performance is similar...

Answer (score 0):

`CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING` disables asynchronous kernel launches and should be used for debugging only.

See https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution for detailed information.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I helps, but I still did not solve the problem. When I run the code with full-batch mode (instead of mini-batch), Pytorch is slightly faster or they are more or less the same. I guess there is a problem is DataLoader but I could not find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the way of data loading between TF an PT are different, TF would generate batch based the consecutive items in the dataset, so that the memory is also consecutive, which is efficient. While PT dataset is a map dataset, it's not that efficient on tabular data, you should consider using a [iterable-style dataset](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#iterable-style-datasets).