# Why is PyTorch significantly slower than Tensorflow? Both are running CUDA

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pytorch, tensorflow2.0

I was just testing out the speeds between tensorflow 2.0 and pytorch 2.0 (since I'm just starting to learn pytorch), and from what I've realized, with the exact same model architecture, same batch size, same optimizer, and both are running CUDA, the pytorch one takes about 3 times as long to run (1 minute of tf vs 3 minutes of pyt), also with a worse accuracy (83% for the validation set for tf and 78% for pyt).

Here is the code for tensorflow:

```py
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(1e-3), loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=20, batch_size=64, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
```

And here is the code for pytorch:

```py
device = torch.device("cuda")

training_data = datasets.FashionMNIST(
    root="data",
    train=True,
    download=True,
    transform=ToTensor()
)

test_data = datasets.FashionMNIST(
    root="data",
    train=False,
    download=True,
    transform=ToTensor()
)

train_dataloader = DataLoader(training_data, batch_size=64)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=64)

class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.linear_relu_stack = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(28*28, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(512, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(512, 10),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.flatten(x)
        logits = self.linear_relu_stack(x)
        return logits

model = NeuralNetwork()
model.to(device)

learning_rate = 1e-3
batch_size = 64
epochs = 5
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

def train_loop(dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)

    model.train()
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)
        pred = model(X)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        if batch % 100 == 0:
            loss, current = loss.item(), (batch + 1) * len(X)
            print(f"loss: {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}]")


def test_loop(dataloader, model, loss_fn):
    model.eval()
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    num_batches = len(dataloader)
    test_loss, correct = 0, 0

    with torch.no_grad():
        for X, y in dataloader:
            X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)
            pred = model(X)
            test_loss += loss_fn(pred, y).item()
            correct += (pred.argmax(1) == y).type(torch.float).sum().item()

    test_loss /= num_batches
    correct /= size
    print(f"Test Error: \n Accuracy: {(100*correct):>0.1f}%, Avg loss: {test_loss:>8f} \n")
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

epochs = 20
for t in range(epochs):
    print(f"Epoch {t+1}\n-------------------------------")
    train_loop(train_dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
    test_loop(test_dataloader, model, loss_fn)
print("Done!")
```

What I've noticed is that tensorflow uses about 60% of my CUDA, and all of my dedicated GPU memory, while pytorch goes on and off between 0% and 30%, and not using much GPU memory at all.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71718769/why-is-my-pytorch-code-significantly-slower-than-tensorflow) exists, but that was due to `CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING`, which is not present in my code.

**Specs:**

- RTX 3060
- Intel i710700, overclocked to ~4.2GHz
- 64GB memory

**Edit**: I've tried upping the workers and pinning memory for Dataloaders, but it only saved around 15 seconds for 20 epochs, and `torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = True` doesn't help at all.

Comment: Print device `device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")`  and check the **CUDA Compatibility** and **PyTorch Version**

Comment: @I_Al-thamary can confirm that the device is cuda after running the print. cuda toolkit version 11.8.0, cudnn 8.1.0.77 and pytorch 2.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was running a test to optimize num_workers outlined in [this medium article](https://chtalhaanwar.medium.com/pytorch-num-workers-a-tip-for-speedy-training-ed127d825db7), I figured that it my DataLoader that is slowing me down. After looking through the documentation, I came across `persistent_workers=True`, which solved the problem for me.

The code went from ~3 minutes to under ~25 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I have converted your code from Tensorflow to [Pytorch](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1y_v9JR-Qo2Wtxa31P1y4dMeqKhLSLFK4?usp=sharing) and it works faster so check the version of the code and use it on your device.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

# Define the model
class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(28*28, 512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 512)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(512, 10)   

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)   
        return x

# Load the data
training_data = datasets.FashionMNIST(
    root="data",
    train=True,
    download=True,
    transform=ToTensor()
)

test_data = datasets.FashionMNIST(
    root="data",
    train=False,
    download=True,
    transform=ToTensor()
)

train_loader = DataLoader(training_data, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=64)

# Create the model and move it to CUDA if available
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model = NeuralNetwork().to(device)

# Define loss and optimizer
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)

# Training loop
for epoch in range(10):
    model.train()
    for images, labels in train_loader:
        images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)

        # Forward pass
        pred = model(images)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, labels)

        # Backward pass and optimization
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    print(f"Epoch {epoch}: Loss: {loss.item()}")

# Validate on the test data
model.eval()
correct = 0
total = 0
with torch.no_grad():
    for images, labels in test_loader:
        images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
        pred = model(images)
        _, predicted = torch.max(pred, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

accuracy = correct / total
print(f'Accuracy: {accuracy * 100}%')
```